# Representation of pairs

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write a representation of pairs that does not use `cons`, `car` or `cdr` but still follows the property of pairs, i.e.,  `(car (cons x y))` should be `x` and `(cdr (cons x y))` should be `y`.
So here is one solution that I got from the SICP book:

```lisp
(define (special-cons x y) 
   (lambda (m) (m x y)))
```

I was able to write another solution but it can only allow numbers:

```lisp
(define (special-cons a b)
  (* (expt 2 a)
     (expt 3 b)))

(define (num-divs n d)
  (define (iter x result)
    (if (= 0 (remainder x d))
        (iter (/ x d) (+ 1 result))
        result))
  (iter n 0))

(define (special-car x)
  (num-divs x 2))

(define (special-cdr x)
  (num-divs x 3))
```

Is there any other solution that allows for pairs for any object x and object y?

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate? My solution is for pairs of numbers. I am trying to implement for pairs of any object

Comment: I'd like to know what Scheme implementation you are using - is it Racket, Chicken, Bigloo, Guile, Gambit, or any other?

Comment: An interesting question, but too broad for Stack Overflow: *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."*  There are lots of ways that you could represent pairs:  numerically, as you've mentioned; lexical closures, as you saw in SICP;  record data structures; 2-element arrays; strings with some sort of value->string encoding; etc.  And it would depend on the language implementation, too.  With a symbolic interpreter, you wouldn't need *any* implementation, but just axioms or reduction rules: *(car (cons x y)) ↦ x* and *(cdr (cons x y)) ↦ y*.

Comment: Couldn't anything you'd like be transformed to either a number or `special-cons` with numbers? How the implementation actually encodes all objects are not known for the user but if you are going to make `cons` you will get your hands dirty.

Answer (score 2):

What about structs (Racket) or record-types (R6RS)?

In Racket:

```
#lang racket

(struct cell (x y))

(define (ccons x y) (cell x y))
(define (ccar cl)   (cell-x cl))
(define (ccdr cl)   (cell-y cl))
(define (cpair? cl) (cell? cl))

(define x (ccons 1 2))
(cpair? x)
=> #t
(ccar (ccons 1 2))
=> 1
(ccdr (ccons 3 4))
=> 4
```

Comment: @user3450695 Not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good way of doing it.

```
#lang racket 

(define (my-cons x y)
  (lambda (p)
    (if (= p 1) x y)))

(define (my-car pair)
  (pair 1))
(define (my-cdr pair)
  (pair 2))
```

Here is the test

```
> (my-car (my-cons 1 '(2 3 4)))
1
> (my-cdr (my-cons 1 '(2 3 4)))
'(2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic Ableson and Sussman procedural implementation from [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (section 2.1.3)*](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%25_sec_2.1.3):

```
(define (cons x y)
  (define (dispatch m)
    (cond ((= m 0) x)
          ((= m 1) y)
          (else (error "Argument not 0 or 1 -- CONS" m))))
  dispatch)

(define (car z)
  (z 0))

(define (cdr z)
  (z 1))
```

Rptx's solution is roughly equivalent, and this is presented for reference.